# Preventing code duplication in procedurally similar functions that have different output?

Tags: c++, code-duplication

We've some function `foo(g, v, output)` that accepts a vertex `v` searches some graph `g` for nearby vertices and returns some vector of information about the path (steps) it took during that search.

Now the steps are a big struct (getting bigger) and we often just want some specific datum (member of the struct) from each step.

The issue is that we now have multiple functions (duplicate code) doing something like this:

```
foo_get_xs(g, v, result) {
  // initialize vectors needed to catch output from foo (1)
  foo(g, v, output); // (2)
  // parse output to get only xs // (3)
}

foo_get_xs(g, v, result) {
  // initialize vectors needed to catch output from foo
  foo(g, v, output);
  // parse output to get only ys
}

foo_get_xs(g, v, result) {
  // initialize vectors needed to catch output from foo
  foo(g, v, output);
  // parse output to get only zs
}
```

How could you make it so there is only one function that accepts an enum possibly and returns a vector filled by the desired field?

The issue is that each field is of a different type. Other than that we duplicate (1), (2) and most of (3).

* In reality it's actually worse because we actually need to test with every `v` so there is a function that calls `foo_xs`, a function that calls `foo_ys` and so on...

Comment: Try to generalize the initialization and parsing code as much as possible, and turn that into separate functions as well. Much more is harder to say without seeing more code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Will still have five or seven functions calling the same init process and the running the same functionality and doing pretty much the same parsing, only that it's extracting a different field. In theory macros would be splendid but people frown up those for some reason.

Comment: @zehelvion Why can't you just run once to get the result struct and then retrieve the results you need from that without rerunning?

Comment: @zstewart The result struct is big and contains many fields so collecting all the data is wasteful and would require us to allocate more memory. Besides this would move the problem to a more disturbing place. We'd have a bunch of foo_get_whole_struct in a bunch of functions, followed by some transform... Since we know the transform is coming, wouldn't it be a kindness to keep it in the black box?

Comment: Does `foo()` not return the whole struct? Wouldn't the memory be allocated anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to pass a callback function which is invoked on every step along the path.

Then you would provide several functions that fill a vector with the desired field. Unfortunately, the vector needs to be abstract.

Alternatively, use a template for the different field types that you need. This will avoid duplication of the source code.

You can also consider using a vector of references to the desired nodes, and transfer the individual fields as a post-processing operation.

Comment: That sounds like an easy solution that is simple to implement. :D

Comment: Er, which of the suggestions ?

Comment: The first one sounded good but abstracting the vector may be cumbersome. The third one is probably what we should have done. DUH
thanks

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, boost-graph uses the `visitor` concept. Each graph algorithm uses a visitor type and calls the visitor's methods when graph traversal events occur.

For instance the DFS visitor must define a method for the `discover vertex` event and another method for the `finish vertex` event.

In your case you would define one visitor implementation for each one of your `foo_get_XXX()` function, and this visitor would only report the useful information.

**References**

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/visitor_concepts.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/DFSVisitor.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
enum Field { xs, ys, zs };
template<Field f>
struct FieldGetter;

template<>
struct FieldGetter<xs> {
   typedef int type;
   static int get( const BigStructure &o ) { return o.xs; }
}
...

template<Field f, typename T=FieldGetter<f>::type>
std::vector<T> foo_get_xs(g, v, result) {
   // initialize vectors needed to catch output from foo
  foo(g, v, output);
  // parse output to get only ys
  std::vector<T> res;
  for( const auto &o : output )
      res.emplace_back( FieldGetter<f>::get( o ) );
  return res;
}
```

It is difficult to say more, as you do not provide enough information